# Simplicity of quotient group

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading through some lecture notes which state:

> To show G/K is simple we will show the only normal subgroups of G
>   lying between K and G are K and G

This seems as though I'd need to use an isomorphism theorem, but I can't quite see why it's true.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you need is, with your notation:

**Theorem**: there exists a $1-1$ correspondence between the subgroups of the quotient group $\;G/K\;$ and the subgroups of $\;G\;$ *containing* $\;K\;$ , given by:

$$G/K\ge\overline H\mapsto H:=\left\{\,x\in G\;/\; xK\in\overline H\right\} $$

and

$$K\le H\le G\;,\;\;H\mapsto H/K:=\left\{\,hK\;/\;h\in H\right\}$$

This correspondence maps normal subgroups to corresponding normal subgroups and respects index.

You can google it under "correspondence theorem" or "Fourth Isomorphism Theorem"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the natural map $q:G\to G/K$. Suppose $G/K$ is not simple, so there is some $1<N\triangleleft G/K$. You can check that $K<q^{-1}(N)\triangleleft G$. Hence if there are no normal subgroups of $G$ lying between $K$ and $G$ other than $K$ and $G$ then $G/K$ must be simple